# Setting up Reachability to monitor connectivity and show an Alert

Tags: ios, ios5, uialertview, reachability

What I am trying to achieve, is monitor any internet connectivity? So the phone needs an active connection to the internet. If it does display a UIAlertView with the option to Try Again (try the connection again to see if it has changed).

I am trying to use Reachability and connection to the api.parse.com link.

In my AppDelegate I call the setup of Reachability like this:

```
// Use Reachability to monitor connectivity
[self monitorReachability];
```

The monitorReachability is setup like this:

```
- (void)monitorReachability {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:ReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

self.hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"api.parse.com"];
[self.hostReach startNotifier];

self.internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[self.internetReach startNotifier];

self.wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
[self.wifiReach startNotifier];
```

}

I also have the reachability changed method as follows:
EDIT - updated method

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification* )note {
Reachability *curReach = (Reachability *)[note object];
NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
NSLog(@"Reachability changed: %@", curReach);
networkStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
    NSLog(@"NOT REACHABLE");
    return;
} else {
    NSLog(@"REACHABLE");
}
```

What I am trying to understand is the responses back. From the above it looks like I have a pointer to the current status and I am not sure how to use this. Basically I want an if statement to check if that link is reachable via the internet connection, if its not I can through an AlertView. I can then setup a boolean for the UIAlertView to use i.e. showingConnectionAlert, which can then be brought down when the connection is changed and picked up. I am unsure where to put this too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to use the Reachability class is to import the Reachability.h into your rootViewController or whatever one is going to need the connection, then simply run this code...

```
 Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

 NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
 if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
 NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   
//Alert View in here      
} 
else {        
//Do something in here with the connecion e.g:

[self performSelector:@selector(startNSURLRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0];

}
```

That should simplify the process a bit.. let me know how you get on. T

Comment: I have added an EDIT to my question. You can see that I check the networkStatus for NotReachable. Does this mean I am checking for Internet Connectivity or for Host Connectivity? In the first method in my question I setup a Notifier for both Host and Internet Connection. Does this just mean that each change of reachability albeit internet connection or host, the second method is called??